# Static weaving of entities spread over multiple jars fails with EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I have several entities spread in multiple jars.
An entity located in jar X contains a collection of entities from jar Y.
When I try to do static weaving on jar X I get the following error:

> Exception Description: [class MyEntity] uses a non-entity [class MyOtherEntity] as target entity in the relationship attribute [method getMyOtherEntities].

The error is related to the following stack:

> at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.nonEntityTargetInRelationship(ValidationException.java:1360)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.RelationshipAccessor.getReferenceDescriptor(RelationshipAccessor.java:538)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.RelationshipAccessor.processJoinTable(RelationshipAccessor.java:692)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ManyToManyAccessor.process(ManyToManyAccessor.java:160)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1489)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1726)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:535)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:550)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1469)

Both entities are annotated with @Entity and worked fine with Hibernate.
Both classes are in the classpath and I've checked in the debugger that MyOtherEntity is found and annotated as expected.

Is it possible to use static weaving while the entities are spread in multiple jars?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try specifying dependent jar while weaving

**Snippet from Ant [EclipseLink weave Ant Task](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving)**

```
 <weave  source="c:\myjar.jar"
        target="c:\wovenmyjar.jar"
        persistenceinfo="c:\myjar-containing-persistenceinfo.jar">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="c:\myjar-dependent.jar"/>
    </classpath>

</weave>
```

Comment: I'm working with the eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin. I've debugged the weaving process and MyOtherEntity is on the classpath.